# Symfony 4 logs in as anonymous after login_check

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 4, when I log in as a user via a login form, it posts the data to /login_check it identifies and authentificates the user correctly and then, when it redirects the user to the target path, it reauthentificates as an Anonymous user.

I have looked and followed with xdebug all the authentification process and it actually logs in the user, redirects the user and reauthentificates as an anon user. I have no clue as per what could cause this.

When using the **Remember me** functionality everything works as expected so this is only when not using it.

[image]

The 302 Redirect "POST @login (2c1c05)" is actually logged in as shown here below

[image]

And the security tab displays the user correctly:

[image]

However, the redirect logs out the user and reauthentificates as an anon user:

[image]
[image]

My security configuration looks like this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\Current\CurrentUser:
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 5000
            encode_as_base64: true
        App\Entity\Legacy\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 0
            encode_as_base64: false
            id: app.security.legacy_digest
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: sha512

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory_provider, legacy_entity_provider, current_entity_provider]
        in_memory_provider:
            memory:
                users:
                    bar:
                        password:           sX49rzTmjz3+u9XFIkpphfNxjKHMrPWP7Y6l7sKkadWIgOFuYo+Ixjj6iMCeWr0LlUh9EXfi5nw5lgz4W5LDKA==
                        roles:              [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
        legacy_entity_provider:
            entity:
                class:              App\Entity\Legacy\User
                manager_name:       legacy
                property: username

        current_entity_provider:
            entity:
                class:              App\Entity\Current\CurrentUser
                property:           username
                manager_name:       current


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            provider: chain_provider
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login
                username_parameter: _username
                password_parameter: _password
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: /

    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:      [ROLE_USER]
```

My login form:

```
<form id="login-form" action="/login" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="login">{% trans %}label.login{% endtrans %}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}"/>
                    <label for="password">{% trans %}label.password{% endtrans %}</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control mb-2" id="password" name="_password"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path(('myaccount_fr_fr' )) }}"/>
                    <button id="login-button" type="submit" class="btn mb-2  btn-secondary btn-block btn-submit_FX text-uppercase">
                        {% trans %}button.loginSubmit{% endtrans %}
                    </button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

The login route path:

```
login:
    path: /login
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::login
```

The SecurityController:

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('user/login.html.twig', array (
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the entire code of the class of user `Raphael1234`, I suppose it should be `App\Entity\Legacy\User`. Do you have the same behaviour with the other two types of users (user bar and one user from `App\Entity\Current\CurrentUser`)?

Comment: There's an error on your firewall definition: you need to set `pattern: /`

Comment: @Nek that did not resolve the issue although it could have had

Comment: @ste my `in_memory_provider` and `current_entity_provider` seem to work perfectly which narrows down the issue to `legacy_entity_provider` being the sole entity provider that redirects users weirdly after correctly loging in users

Comment: Found the issue : using AdvancedUserInterface was at the origin of this bug. I will investigate further in the future. Thank you !

Comment: @db306 that's what I supposed. Have a look here https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#understanding-serialize-and-how-a-user-is-saved-in-the-session maybe you didn't implement correctly serialize and unserialize methods - if they differ (e.g. serialized and unserialized properties are not identical), the user is logged out immediatly for security reasons.

Comment: @ste the serialized and unserialized are exactly the same, I was very careful with that as per the specs. End of the day I used the UserInterface instead of the Advanced and will look further into it as soon as possible to make sure there are no bugs related to symfony (as I'm using the very latest symfony version 4.0.10) but I'm pretty sure I did somethign stupid around isEnabled() function or something along those lines. Thank you !

Comment: Although I must say that it was a strange behaviour, no errors, it logs you in and logs you out within the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are curious behaviours sometimes when wrongly configuring a set of features for our applications and instead of having some sort of error that we need to decypher we only have some sort of collateral effect or behaviour in our application. In this case, when logging in, it would automatically log out the user without giving any further error of whatsoever.

When using AdvancedUserInterface there are 4 extra functions that the User Entity needs to implement

```
public function isAccountNonExpired();

public function isAccountNonLocked();

public function isCredentialsNonExpired();

public function isEnabled();
```

Note that this user implementation is [now deprecated](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-deprecated-the-advanceduserinterface) from 4.1 onwards and the use of  [User Checkers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html) is now advised instead.

If you follow the documentation you will notice that within the first example you will find this:

On the first example:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }
```

And then lower down, in the section Forbid Inactive Users (AdvancedUserInterface)

```
public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
```

Well this does not work as you would expect it to work. On subsequent requests, when the user is hydrated by the ORM the object is not fully constructed and isActive returns null. You need to get isActive from the database itself or force it from the constant itself:

```
private $isActive = true;
```

Comment: this sounds strange. `$isActive` should be populated from doctrine the same way that happens for the other fields. Are you sure that in your dB that field is true (instead of null)? `__construct()` is not executed when the entity is fetched from dB, but only when it's first instanciated (i.e. with `new`)

Comment: The issue is that the example on symfony docs displays on the construct method the `$this->isActive = true;` which I thought was sufficient enough. I thought that was enough to tell the authentication object : 'Yes this account is active' but that's not true. You cannot force the active field via the constructor but only via the variable definition as stated above. I think this is bizare and the exact explanation as per why the constructor isn't sufficient enough isn't completely clear yet.